# "Cannot Open DDE Link to": Problems with Adobe Acrobat Pro and WinEdt

Tags: errors, viewers, winedt, adobe

While using the 2017 release of Adobe Acrobat DC, I get the error

[image: error WinEdt Adobe Acrobat DC 2017]

every time I run PDFLatex with my PDF open. When I use PDF Search, I get the same error.

Does anybody know what do I have to change in the `.edt` files to make it work?

Comment: Update your winedt. Alex said he has changed the macros. Alternatively you would need to change adobe.edt to set the service to acroviewA17 (or acroviewR17).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Support for Adobe Acrobat DC 2017 has been added only in WinEdt 10.2 Build 20170413.

The name of the DDE service is, in the case of Acrobat DC Pro 2017, `AcroviewA17`, while in the case of Adobe Reader DC 2017, `AcroviewR17`.

You have to insert this value in the `Options` --> `Execution Modes` --> `PDF Viewer` --> `Adobe DDE Service Blues` field and then press OK, as in the image below.

[image]

Notice that it might not work if you have a local copy of `Adobe.edt` in the path `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Config`. In this case, simply delete that file and restart WinEdt.

---

If you can't upgrade to the latest version of WinEdt, you can instead open a local copy of the file `Adobe.edt` from the menu `Options` --> `Options Interface` --> `Advanced Configuration` --> `PDF Macros` --> `Adobe Blues`.

[image]

In this file, replace the line at the very end of it

```
// Assign(!"Acro-DDE_Service",!"AcroviewR11");
```

with the following

```
Assign(!"Acro-DDE_Service",!"AcroviewA17");
```

then save the file and restart WinEdt.

---

### Addendum: Name of the DDE service for different versions of Adobe DC

- **Adobe Reader DC 2015**: `AcroviewR15`
- **Acrobat DC Pro 2015**: `AcroviewA15`
- **Adobe Reader DC 2017**: `AcroviewR17`
- **Acrobat DC Pro 2017**: `AcroviewA17`
- **Adobe Reader DC 2018**: `AcroviewR18`
- **Acrobat DC Pro 2018**: `AcroviewA18`

Unless Adobe changes its naming convention, for future versions it suffices to change the last two digits according to the year version.

Comment: Thank you very much! installing WinEdt 10 solves the problem. Thank you! Francisco

Comment: Let me bring in the new year by saying that installing WinEdt 10, MikTex 2.9, and and the latest version of Acrobat just now required me to change the DDE name to AcroviewA19 in order to get everything to work properly. ;-)

Comment: Using WinEdt 10 and MikTex, I just had to change the DDE name to AcroviewR19 and then I had to restart my computer to get it working,

Comment: Doesn't work in 2021.  I changed the DDE name to AcroviewR21, but when Acroread is open, PDFTexify cannot run (gives the post's error).

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 it is AcroViewA21. You can find out the registred name of the DDE server by looking it up in the registry:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application

Best regards

Rolf