# PDFTexify Errors

Tags: errors, viewers, winedt, adobe

This morning, WinEdt 10.2 start exhibiting the problem with Adobe Reader DC in that I have to close the reader each time I want to compile with PDFTexify.  Here is the error that I get:

```
Cannot Open DDE Link to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRD32.exe
Service" AcroviewA17
Topic: Control
```

I have already tried reinstalling WinEdt with the latest build and the Adobe Reader is up-to-date.  I have also tried the modifications discussed in previous forums in editing through the options interface.

I have also tried editing the Adobe.edt file which now reads:

```
// As of Adobe DC DDE Service is version-dependent (eg. AcroViewR17 or AcroViewA17)

Assign(!'Acro-DDE_Service',!'Acroview');

  // Adobe Blues: Registry does not contain proper value for Adobe X!
  // http://forums.adobe.com/message/3323310
  IfNum('%!3','10','<',!'JMP(!"DDE_OK");');
  // Add R or A + Major Version...
  //UF LetReg(4,'R%!3');
  LetReg(4,'R17');
  //\UF
  FindInString("%$('PDF-View');",'Acrobat.exe',1,2,1000,1);
  //UF IfOK(!"LetReg(4,'A%!3');");
  IfOK(!"LetReg(4,'A18');");
  //\UF
  Assign(!'Acro-DDE_Service','%$("Acro-DDE_Service");%!4');
  // Prompt('DDE Service: %$("Acro-DDE_Service");');
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401386/winedt-has-stopped-being-able-to-close-pdf-files/401420#401420 help?

Comment: I have edited my Adobe.edt file located in the directory:  C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt10\Config  so that it looks exactly like what is listed on that suggestion, but to no avail.