# WinEdt: How to open the new PDF compiled without closing the old-one?, compiled minutes ago

Tags: errors, viewers, winedt, adobe

Using WinEdt 10.2 on Windows, when I compiled a doc, automatically WinEdt opens  the PDF with Acrobat Reader. And If I didn´t close that viewed file, I recompiled again  and  WinEdt closes the old PDF and show me the new one.

But I made any changes, or WinEdt copied the settings from my installed WinEdt 9,... and now... If I close the PDF, and then compile, WinEdt opens the just-compiled PDF with Acrobat Reader

BUT

If I didn´t close the old PDF, Winedt can´t open the new PDF with Acrobat Reader as weeks ago, and show me that message:
[image]

How could I show the new PDFs without closing the old one just-compiled a minutes ago?

I usually use [image]

Excuse me for my little English.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401386/winedt-has-stopped-being-able-to-close-pdf-files/401420#401420

Comment: Anyway, the recommended viewer is `SumatraPDF`: lightweight (12Mb vs 330 Mb), ultra fast, has a 64 bits version, and can perform direct and inverse search!

Comment: @Bernard I think this is opinion based, isn't it? I'd recommend MuPDF as it doesn't come with any useless gui and just shows the PDF (though it is bigger than Sumatra), btw :)

Comment: @Skillmon: It's not entirely opinion-based; Acrobat Reader does lock the pdf when you recompile, whereas SumatraPDf does not. Incidentally, SumatraPDF is based on MuPDF.

Comment: @Bernard but it is opinion based which of the non-locking viewers you use (just don't use Adobe's...)