Users of WINEdt 5.5 on a PC With OS Window 11 and Adobe product version 24.004.20272
I'm  using WINEdt 5.5 on a PC With OS Window 11 and  Adobe  product version 24.004.20272. The problem is I can't PDF texify my TeX version  of the document. It does PDF texify, but I get error messages for open document, close document in EXEC file. But it used to work very well with Reader 11.  What changes are needed in both these files so that I stop getting error messages?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up -- "The problem is I can't PDFtexify my [document]. It does PDFtexify..." -- is a bit confusing. WinEdt is just a front-end to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution is installed on your system, when did you last update it, and did you experience any problems during that update? And, which Adobe product -- Acrobat, maybe? -- do you use at present? Aside: I believe the current version number of WinEdt is 11.2 -- any chance you could obtain an update of your 5.5 version?

With W11 is worth to invest to WinEdt 11. It is not so expensive but is far more capable ...

adobe regularly changes the names need in the DDE-command, and then you need to adapt that in winedt too. But winedt 5.5 is very old and I at least do not remember how it was done there. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366103/2388

Thanks to each one of the team members answering my question.
